# Return part of list from model based on query ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following `model`:

```
    public class Vendor
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
            public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [MinLength(10)]
            public string Telephone { get; set; }

            public string Notes { get; set; }

            public Currency Currency { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Currency")]
            public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }

            public List<Translation> Translations { get; set; }

            public byte? Rating { get; set; } 
        }
```

and I'm implementing an api that will return all the vendors from the database. The problem is that I need to include in the JSON object that is returned, only the `Translations` that meet some specifications.
For now, my `API Controller` looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<VendorDto> GetVendors(string sourceLanguage = null, string targetLanguage = null, string service = null)
        {
            var vendorsQuery = _context.Vendors
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.SourceLanguage))
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.TargetLanguage))
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.Service))
                .Include(v => v.Currency);

            var result = vendorsQuery.ToList();

            IEnumerable<Translation> filteredTranslationsResults;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceLanguage))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetLanguage))
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(service))
                    {
                        filteredTranslationsResults = vendorsQuery
                            .SelectMany(v => v.Translations)
                            .Where(t => t.SourceLanguage.Name == sourceLanguage)
                            .Where(t => t.TargetLanguage.Name == targetLanguage)
                            .Where(t => t.Service.Name == service);
                        vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery
                            .Where(v => v.Translations.Intersect(filteredTranslationsResults).Any());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filteredTranslationsResults = vendorsQuery
                            .SelectMany(v => v.Translations)
                            .Where(t => t.SourceLanguage.Name == sourceLanguage)
                            .Where(t => t.TargetLanguage.Name == targetLanguage);
                        vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery
                            .Where(v => v.Translations.Intersect(filteredTranslationsResults).Any());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filteredTranslationsResults = vendorsQuery
                            .SelectMany(v => v.Translations)
                            .Where(t => t.SourceLanguage.Name == sourceLanguage);
                    vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery
                        .Where(v => v.Translations.Intersect(filteredTranslationsResults).Any());
                }
            }

            return vendorsQuery
                .ToList()
                .Select(Mapper.Map<Vendor, VendorDto>);
        }
```

so basically I need to return all the `Vendors` that have the `source/target language` and the `service` that is passed as parameters and in the `vendors` returned, i need to have only that `translations` with that `source/target language` and `service`. With my current `Controller` implementation, if it finds a `Vendor` that has in his `Translations` list, the `translation` that I'm looking for, it returns that `Vendor` with all his `translations`, because `Intersect` just says that it's true and then get all.
What do I need to change so the returned object (`Vendor`) will contain only the `translation` that I'm looking for?

**UPDATE**: `Translation` model:

```
public class Translation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Language SourceLanguage { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Source Language")]
        public int SourceLanguageId { get; set; }

        public Language TargetLanguage { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Target Language")]
        public int TargetLanguageId { get; set; }

        public Service Service { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Service")]
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public UnitMeasure UnitMeasure { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Unit Measure")]
        public int UnitMeasureId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you add the model for `Translation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is probably pretty bad, but based on your model this is one thing i came up with:

Please note, however, that depending on how many vendors and translations you have it may be MUCH faster to call tolist BEFORE applying predicates (e.g. if you have under 100K records it is probably faster to pull all of them down).

```
public IEnumerable<VendorDto> GetVendors(string sourceLanguage = null, string targetLanguage = null, string service = null)
        {
            var vendorsQuery = _context.Vendors
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.SourceLanguage))
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.TargetLanguage))
                .Include(v => v.Translations.Select(t => t.Service))
                .Include(v => v.Currency)
                // consider adding a .ToList() right here based on how many records you have


                Expression<Func<Translation, bool>> sourceLanguagePredicate = z => z.SourceLanguage.Name == sourceLanguage;
                Expression<Func<Translation, bool>> targetLanguagePredicate = z => z.TargetLanguage.Name == targetLanguage;
                Expression<Func<Translation, bool>> servicePredicate = z => z.Service.Name == service;

                var hasSource = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceLanguage);
                var hasTarget = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetLanguage);
                var hasService = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(service);
                if(hasSource)
                {
                    vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery.Where(x => x.Translations.AsQueryable().Any(sourceLanguagePredicate));
                }

                if(hasTarget)
                {
                    vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery.Where(x => x.Translations.AsQueryable().Any(targetLanguagePredicate));
                }

                if(hasService)
                {
                    vendorsQuery = vendorsQuery.Where(x => x.Translations.AsQueryable().Any(servicePredicate));
                }

                var vendors = vendorsQuery.ToList();

                foreach(var vendor in vendors)
                {
                    if(hasSource)
                    {           
                        vendor.Translations = vendor.Translations.Where(sourceLanguagePredicate).ToList();
                    }

                    if(hasTarget)
                    {           
                        vendor.Translations = vendor.Translations.Where(targetLanguagePredicate).ToList();
                    }

                    if(hasService)
                    {           
                        vendor.Translations = vendor.Translations.Where(servicePredicate).ToList();
                    }
                }

                return vendors.Select(Mapper.Map<Vendor, VendorDto>);
        }
```

Comment: x.Translations.Any change to
x.Translations.AsQueryable().Any

Also, if someone is reading this, there's 2 typos at expressions, comparing sourceLanguage with target language and sourceLanguage with service, but correcting those actually resolved my problem.